BLER of extended BCH code
I need to get a block error rate curve for an extended BCH code by one bit. The code length for MATLAB function for BCH decoder has to be $2^m-1$, but I need it to be $2^m.$ Could you help how to get such a performance curve using the available algorithms?

I don't know how exactly MATLAB defines block error rate for a BCH decoder, and how it calculates it, and so this answer is a bit speculative.
A BCH decoder can produce output that is

A valid codeword which is either the same as the transmitted codeword (and so the output is correct) or is different from the transmitted codeword (and so a block error has occurred but the decoder is totally unaware of this)

OR

fail to decode, producing output that is not a valid codeword at all, and also an indication that something is awry, letting everyone know that the output is unreliable.

Thus, discussions of BCH decoder performance (indeed, any bounded-distance decoder in general) ought to distinguish between decoder error (producing a wrong codeword without any indication that something is wrong) and decoder failure, when the output is not a valid codeword and the decoder is telling everyone that the output is not a valid codeword. Should this count as an error? Maybe, maybe not. In some systems, a re-transmission can be requested in case of decoder failure while in others, no such re-transmission is possible. In most well-designed decoder systems, it is true that
$$P_{\text{decoder output correct}} \gg P_{\text{decoder failure}} \gg P_{\text{decoder output incorrect}}.$$
If MATLAB is lumping decoder failures and decoder errors together as errors, its calculations of what the OP calls BLER are most likely quite simple.  $P_{\text{decoder output correct}}$ is just the probability that no more than $t$ transmission errors occurred on the channel, and so
$$P_{\text{decoder output correct}} = \sum_{i=0}^t \binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$
where $n$ is the block length of the code, $t$ is the error-correcting capability, and $p$ is the channel bit error rate. (This formula can be used for the extended BCH code as well as long as we remember to change $n=2^m-1$ to $n=2^m$).  The BLER then is just $1- P_{\text{decoder output correct}}$.  If MATLAB simulates the BCH decoder to determine the BLER empirically, then of course, the above calculation is irrelevant.
What about extended BCH codes?  Well, the extended BCH code cannot correct more than $t$ errors, but it can detect some more (though by no means all additional) instances of decoder failure.  So, while there is some minor change between probabilities of decoder failure and decoder error, if we are lumping the two events into one, there is not much difference. In using the formula $$P_{\text{decoder output correct}} = \sum_{i=0}^t \binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$
one should keep in mind that not only is $n$ larger by $1$ as already mentioned previously, but also the $kE_b$ joules of energy is now used to transmit $2^m$ channel bits instead of $2^m-1$ channel bits, and so $p$, the channel bit error rate, is just a tad larger.
You might find this previous answer of mine useful. For yet another way that BCH decoders can fail at their task, see the papers D. V. Sarwate and R. D. Morrison, "Decoder Malfunction in BCH Decoders," IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, pp. 894-899, July 1990, and M. Srinivasan and D. V. Sarwate, "Malfunction in Peterson-Gorenstein-Zierler Decoders" IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, pp. 1649-1653, September 1994.

Dear Dilip Sarwate, Thanks very much for your detailed answer. MATLAB uses the Berlekamp-Massey Algorithm as a decoder. May I ask how to apply Chase decoding in this case, where we run the decoder many times by flipping the input symbols to some order, hoping for successful decoding? Is there any way to include it in the formulation above? Thank you.
